# Zend framework album example

Tags: php, pdo, zend-framework2, zend-db-table

Hi I am getting the following error in zendframework 2 in album example.  Using PHP 5.6.2 version with XAMPP. Any clue for this issue..

Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

File:
    `C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php:555`

Message:
     `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter`

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Album\Module.php(42): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Zend\\Db\\Adapter...')
#1 [internal function]: Album\Module->Album\{closure}(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'albumtablegatew...', 'AlbumTableGatew...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(934): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'albumtablegatew...', 'AlbumTableGatew...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1094): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'albumtablegatew...', 'AlbumTableGatew...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(634): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('albumtablegatew...', 'AlbumTableGatew...')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('AlbumTableGatew...', 'albumtablegatew...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Album\Module.php(37): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('AlbumTableGatew...')
#8 [internal function]: Album\Module->Album\{closure}(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'albummodelalbum...', 'Album\\Model\\Alb...')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(934): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'albummodelalbum...', 'Album\\Model\\Alb...')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1094): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'albummodelalbum...', 'Album\\Model\\Alb...')
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(634): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('albummodelalbum...', 'Album\\Model\\Alb...')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Album\\Model\\Alb...', 'albummodelalbum...')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php(37): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Album\\Model\\Alb...')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php(16): Album\Controller\AlbumController->getAlbumTable()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Album\Controller\AlbumController->indexAction()
#17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#22 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\public\index.php(27): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#27 {main}
```

Also showing an Deprecated error :

Deprecated: You are retrieving the service locator from within the class Album\Controller\AlbumController. Please be aware that ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceLocatorAwareInitializer. You will need to update your class to accept all dependencies at creation, either via constructor arguments or setters, and use a factory to perform the injections. in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php on line 258

Comment: Have you register Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter in your module.config.php?

Comment: Please provide some more code here.

Comment: Did you install the application dependencies properly using composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter in module.config.php worked